# Deploying the google translation api in my java server locally and not invoking web service.

Tags: java, google-translate

I want to deploy the google translation api in my java server locally. Is there any option where we can get the translation result either from any jar or something else instead of invoking the web service. Since, data which i need to translate is secure and it cannot be exposed. Could you please provide me the information on deploying the same on application server and not invoking web services.

Google Translation API works great with web service call, but i need something which can be done locally not via web service.

Or is there any other API which i can use for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no jar that you can install and run it locally. You have to call Google Web Services.

Comment: Thanks Osoter for your reply !!!. Google has given the solution for it and they can provide the private google cloud which will increase the efficiency of the code by not hitting the exposed web service which they have provided.